# C# error message "use of unassigned local variable ' var name'

Tags: c#

see the follow 2 codes I get the error message: use of unassigned local variable 'message' on one the other one is 'tempInsurance'

both codes listed below.

Comment: looks like you're joking? or just a little absent-minded?

Comment: Even without the code, I can tell you it's because your local variable is unassigned. Give it a value. The error message is pretty damn straightforward, and you'll get at least a hundred good hits on Google if you take the time to search.

Comment: Please give us your code!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post any code.

Regardless.. the error is because you're using a variable before assigning it a value.

E.g:

```
string name;
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

The compiler wants you to assign a value to this variable before it is used.

E.g:

```
string name = "user3068503"; // assign it a value
Console.WriteLine(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

Without code it's impossible to tell for sure, but I'm sure you're doing something like this:

```
var name;
```

and then calling it in some fashion

```
print(name.ToString());
```

so to fix do something like this:

```
var name = String.Empty;
print(name.ToString());
```

This could be because you're assigning it a value in an if statement, so the assignment might not actually occur:

```
var name;
if(someBool)
    name = "Name";
print(name.ToString());
```

and then you call if afterwards, hence "use of unassigned variable"